# Error: Recursion Depth of 1024 Exceeded During Evaluation

Tags: warning-messages, expression-manipulation

I wrote a function that exchanges integration and summation in an expression.

```
Exchange[Eq_] := 
 Module[{Rule, Expr, S, L}, 
  Rule = Inactive[Integrate][Inactive[Sum][Expr_, S_], L_] -> 
    Inactive[Sum][Inactive[Integrate][Expr, L], S];
  ReplaceAll[Eq, Rule]
  ]
```

and then I tried to test it

```
Eq = Inactive[Integrate][
   Inactive[Sum][Subscript[f, i][x], {i, 1, n}], {x, 1, 2}] == g[x]
Exchange[Eq]
```

and I got

[image]

I couldn't find where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because you overwrote the builtin function `Rule`, and then proceeded trying to use it implicitly through the shortcut form `->`.
This results in Mathematica trying to evaluate `Rule` to obtain the evaluated form of `Rule`, hence the endless loop.

Just replace `Rule` with `rule` and your code works just fine.

Comment: Thanks! So the advice is not to begin the names with capitals! :)